# Extension of a function from the edge.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

How can I extend the function $f\in W^{1-\frac{1}{p},p}(\mathbb R\times\lbrace0\rbrace)$ up to $g\in W^{1,p}(\mathbb R\times(0,\infty))$?

Answer (score 0):

By convolution with a smooth kernel. I sketch the construction in Theorem 15.21 in *A first course in Sobolev spaces* by Leoni.

Choose a smooth function $\varphi$ on $\mathbb R$ so that the support of $\varphi$ is contained in $(-1,1)$ and the integral of $\varphi$ is $1$. For $y>0$, define 
$$
g(x,y) =e^{-y/p} \frac{1}{y} \int_{\mathbb R} \varphi\left(\frac{x-t}{y}\right)f(t)\,dt
$$ 
The factor $e^{-y/p}$ is used to make things integrable over large $y$. The rest is typical mollification, like in the solution of the diffusion equation but with compactly supported kernel (which is more convenient).

I do not reproduce the integral estimates  for $g$ and its derivatives: they take four pages in the book. (Leoni extends from $\mathbb R^{N-1}$ to $\mathbb R^N_+$, but the proof does not simplify much when $N=2$).

Comment: Thanks, you helped me. But I still have some problems with this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/741012/extension-of-the-regularity-results